# Radeon drivers consumes a lot of RAM(commited memory)

Tags: windows-10, memory, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I'm very confused with my Radeon RX 570 usage experience. When i have Radeon drivers installed i see in task manager that my committed memory grows up from 1.8Gb to 3.9Gb while it shows that memory usage still 1.8 Gb. The problem is that "commited memory" shows actual used memory. So it's weird to have so high memory usage after system start. Maybe i'm not alone and anyone has same problem ? I wrote to amd support, but they told me nothing useful (reseat memory, update bios, described reason's why memory usage grows). I have to switch videodriver to windows version when i need all my ram and then switch it back to radeon for games. Am i right that such a big memory usage is not normal ?

Comment: No, commit charge is not “actual used”. It also includes reserved memory that is not used.

Comment: Daniel, i mean that my video card uses this memory by reserving it, so i can't use it myself, so when windows warns me that i can't open new program because i have no free ram(task manager shows that used memory is only 75%, but commited is full) i can free it only by switching videocard driver from radeon to windows version.

Comment: @roma2341 But the Radeon RX 570 has it's own memory. This is why you should run the Radeon drivers which came with the card. Most Rx750 have 4GB to use by themselves, but if you don't run the correct package for the Radeon, it probably won't be able to use that installed memory on the video card. In your BIOS settings it should allow you to allow only so much for video, this is for onboard video, use the lowest value for the onboard video, you might see a difference.

Comment: vssher, i have ryzen 5 3600 without integrated gpu and my bios doesn't show shared ram option for my rx 570

Comment: The memory may be reserved because the desktop or some app uses the 3D mode. If you want to save RAM try to disable all the fancy desktop visualization stuff.

Comment: Sounds like you changed the page file configuration. Revert it to auto mode.

Comment: Daniel, i disabled page file because i have 16 gb of ram

Comment: Robert, i disabled visualization stuff and nothing changed.

Comment: @roma2341 - You need a page file.

Comment: Ramhound, swap is holy war topic, so i won't argue about it

Comment: The page file isn’t swap. It is required on Windows because of the way virtual memory works on Windows. If you don’t have a page file, you are _wasting_ physical RAM.

Comment: Daniel, virtual memory is swap(page file) + RAM. As i know page file is only required for hibernization and if you have not enough physical memory.

Comment: That’s incorrect. The page file is required to back _commit charge_. (It is entirely unrelated to hibernate). Memory that is committed may or may not actually be used. Without having a page file, you have only physical memory to back virtual memory. You are wasting RAM. Use a page file or suffer the consequences. Your choice, really.

Comment: Daniel, i don't think that when process or driver unreasonably eats system resources i should enable swap(page file) to avoid the problem.  I just use my RAM as intended. Actually i didn't mention that i have lack of memory, it's strange to me that my discrete video card use more RAM then my IDE and i asked if it's normal for videocard driver.